# Pandas timedelta from string

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame, `df`, which looks like this:

```
Index   Start_date        End_date
1      17-Oct-2015     19-Oct-2015
2      07-Nov-2015     22-Nov-2015
3      26-Nov-2015     09-Dec-2015
4      25-Oct-2015     13-Nov-2015
5      19-Oct-2015     28-Oct-2015
6      27-Oct-2015     13-Nov-2015
```

The columns `Start_date` and `End_date` are strings. I need to create a third column, `Duration`, which has the time duration in days as a difference between `Start_date` and `End_date`.

I tried

```
df['Duration'] = pd.Timedelta(df['End_date']) - pd.Timedelta(df['Start_date'])
```

and got the error message:

```
ValueError: value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible
```

What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])
print (df)

   Index   Start_date     End_date  Duration
0      1  17-Oct-2015  19-Oct-2015    2 days
1      2  07-Nov-2015  22-Nov-2015   15 days
2      3  26-Nov-2015  09-Dec-2015   13 days
3      4  25-Oct-2015  13-Nov-2015   19 days
4      5  19-Oct-2015  28-Oct-2015    9 days
5      6  27-Oct-2015  13-Nov-2015   17 days
```

Or you can first convert columns and then substract, because `dtype` of columns `End_date` and `Start_date` is `datetime` and `Duration` is `timedelta`:

```
df['End_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_date'])
df['Start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_date'])

df['Duration'] =  df['End_date'] - df['Start_date']
print (df)
   Index Start_date   End_date  Duration
0      1 2015-10-17 2015-10-19    2 days
1      2 2015-11-07 2015-11-22   15 days
2      3 2015-11-26 2015-12-09   13 days
3      4 2015-10-25 2015-11-13   19 days
4      5 2015-10-19 2015-10-28    9 days
5      6 2015-10-27 2015-11-13   17 days

print (df.dtypes)
Index                   int64
Start_date     datetime64[ns]
End_date       datetime64[ns]
Duration      timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

EDIT by comment:

The fastest solution in divide by `np.timedelta64(1, 'D')` and if output is always `int`, use casting with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Duration'] =  ((df['End_date'] - df['Start_date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
print (df)

   Index Start_date   End_date  Duration
0      1 2015-10-17 2015-10-19         2
1      2 2015-11-07 2015-11-22        15
2      3 2015-11-26 2015-12-09        13
3      4 2015-10-25 2015-11-13        19
4      5 2015-10-19 2015-10-28         9
5      6 2015-10-27 2015-11-13        17
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting, I edit answer with converting to `int`